# Upgrade problem /Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dpkg, software-updates

I am trying to upgrade through terminal (preference) and I still got this error which I have not seen yet. I am using Ubuntu KDE (Kubuntu 16.04 xenial).

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgeoclue0 libxapian-1.3-5 python3-xapian1.3 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic (4.4.0-38.57) ...
Running depmod.
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs: not found
Failed to create initrd image.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.38.40); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.  
                                                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already  
 yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it can't find the file /usr/sbin/update-initramfs and that initramfs-tools might not be properly installed.

You can try the following command to see if it's already installed:

```
sudo dpkg -l |grep initramfs-tools
```

If it isn't installed yet, you can try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install initramfs-tools
```

If it says that it's already installed you could try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools
```